# oracle sql to perform a recursive addition of number field

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to accomplish this in SQL. The logic is a recursive add starting with the first number. Any help with be appreciated

Data Have

```
num_field
22
10
20
30
1
7
7
```

Data Want

```
num_field  Derived
22          22
10          32
20          52
30          82
1           83
7           90
7           97
```

Below is the table creation script with data HAVE

```
CREATE TABLE HAVE (num_field
number(4));
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (22);
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (10);
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (20);
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (30);
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (1);
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (7);
Insert into HAVE (num_field)
Values (7);
```

For anyone interested, the following sql statement solved my problem

`SELECT     num_field
          ,SUM (num_field)  OVER (ORDER BY rownum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) derived
from HAVE;`

Comment: The RANGE clause is redundant in this case, if you use ORDER BY for the SUM function the RANGE is exacly the same between the first row in the partition and row being evaluated,

Comment: Thanks @  Husqvik for the info. I realized also after further digging through that the RANGE (though it works for my own instance since rownum are always unique) was not the right approach

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
select num_field, row_number() over(order by null) as rn
 ,nvl(lag(num_field) over(order by null) , 0) as prev
from tablename
 )
select num_field,
case when rn = (select max(rn) from x) then num_field +
               (select prev from x where rn = (select max(rn)-1 from x))
else num_field + prev 
end as derived
from x
```

You can use `lag` to get the previous row's value and then add up.

Comment: or, y'know, if you're going to use an analytic function: SUM()!

Comment: Thanks vkp for your solution. It didn't get me the desired result that I was looking for